# How to set DateTime to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using C#. I have a string `dateTimeEnd`.

If the string is in right format, I wish to generate a `DateTime` and assign it to eventCustom.DateTimeEnd  of type

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTimeEnd { get; set; }
```

If `dateTimeEnd` is null or empty I need `eventCustom.DateTimeEnd` set to null.

I am trying to achieve this using the following code but I get always null for `eventCustom.DateTimeEnd`.

Could you please help me out to define what is wrong in my code?

```
   DateTime? dateTimeEndResult;
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateTimeEnd))
        dateTimeEndResult = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeEnd);


eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = dateTimeEndResult = true ? (DateTime?)null : dateTimeEndResult;
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

It looks like you just want:

```
eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateTimeEnd)
    ? (DateTime?) null
    : DateTime.Parse(dateTimeEnd);
```

Note that this will throw an exception if `dateTimeEnd` isn't a valid date.

An alternative would be:

```
DateTime validValue;
eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeEnd, out validValue)
    ? validValue
    : (DateTime?) null;
```

That will now set the result to `null` if `dateTimeEnd` isn't valid. Note that `TryParse` handles `null` as an input with no problems.

Comment: Shouldn't this be other way around? I mean when the string contains `"IsNullOrWhiteSpace"`, null value should be assigned to the field, hence `(DateTime?) null` should come after conditional operator

Comment: @sohaiby: Yes, well spotted. Will fix.

Comment: Rather `default(DateTime?)`?

Comment: @GertArnold: They're equivalent - it doesn't matter which you use.

Answer (score 21):

`DateTime` is a non-nullable value type

```
DateTime? newdate = null;
```

You can use a `Nullable<DateTime>`

[c# Nullable Datetime](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateTimeEnd))
    eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeEnd);
else
    eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = null;
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the string is not in the correct format.

Comment: How can `dateTimeEndResult` be `true`? It's a `DateTime?`, not a `bool`.

Comment: Trying this I get Error 2 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'bool'

Comment: @JonSkeet I typed it in as the wrong type when I was testing it. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = dateTimeEndResult = true ? (DateTime?)null : dateTimeEndResult;
```

is same as:

```
eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = dateTimeEndResult = (true ? (DateTime?)null : dateTimeEndResult);
```

because the conditional operator `?` has a higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. That's why you always get null for `eventCustom.DateTimeEnd`. ([MSDN Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173145.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

You can write 
DateTime? newdate = null;

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

```
//declare date object
maxDate: Date;
//assign value

this.maxDate=new Date(event.value._d); //event.value._d is date formate
//setting date Object to null
this.maxDate=null;
```

Comment: you sure that this is valid C#?

Answer (score -1):

Now, I can't use `DateTime?`, I am using `DBNull.Value` for all data types. It works great.

```
eventCustom.DateTimeEnd = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateTimeEnd)
  ? DBNull.Value
  : DateTime.Parse(dateTimeEnd);
```

Comment: `DbNull.Value` is absolutely not the same as `null` and its usage is very limited.