# Case statement in Linq for a nullable datetime field

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq query with nullable datatime field which populate value based on condition.

```
var result=(from t1 in context.table1
            join t2 in context.table2 
            on t1.id equals t2.fieldId
            select new model1
            {
                name= t2.name,
                DateCompleted = t1.Status == "Success" 
                    ? Convert.ToDateTime(t1.CompletedDate)
                    : Null
            }).ToList();
```

Here DateCompleted can be nullable .If status is success then only I need Completed date.Other wise I need to show it null . Now the ": Null" portion is throwing error.

Thanks in advance
Subin

Comment: try using null in place of Null

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769233/how-to-set-datetime-to-null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var result=(from t1 in context.table1
             join t2 in context.table2 
            on t1.id equals t2.fieldId
            select new model1
            {
             name= t2.name,
             DateCompleted = t1.Status == "Success" ? Convert.ToDateTime(t1.CompletedDate): (DateTime?)null
                                                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: You were faster than me: +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
var result=(from t1 in context.table1
            join t2 in context.table2 
            on t1.id equals t2.fieldId
            select new model1
            {
                name= t2.name,
                DateCompleted = t1.Status == "Success" 
                    ? Convert.ToDateTime(t1.CompletedDate)
                    : (DateTime?) null
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nullable date time: default(DateTime?)